# Converting FTP data sync to Azure services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-scheduler

I have an old legacy application built on .NET remoting, and transferring data via XML via with FTP.

Esentially, a CRM system is sending XML files to a directory on the web server, which has a windows service that uses a filewatcher to process the incoming XML file, updating the database.
Similarly, changes on the web application serialize down into an XML file into an out folder, that the CRM polls via FTP every 5 minutes.

Trying to map the best services to convert this to for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Blobs or Azure Files for this.

**Azure Blobs**: This is the lowest cost option, while still providing high throughput. However, note that Azure Blobs do not have File Watcher functionality, so you would have to poll the directory every few minutes to check for a new file. If you delete files after processing them, then this is really easy - all you have to do is list and see if there are any files. If you want to retain the files, then you might have to do more, since the file list will get big over time. Let me know if this is the case and I can suggest some options.

**Azure Files**: This is an SMB share that you can mount from a VM in the same region. This will map pretty closely to your exising filesystem based code, including FileWatcher. However, note that Azure Files can only be mounted by a VM in the same region.